# How do I reduce a list of tuples into one output?

Tags: python, mapreduce, reduce

I just completed a mapper and groupby script. Running it in my terminal gives me a list of tuples:

```
a [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '1')]
b [('1', '0', '0')]
e [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '1')]
f [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0')]
i [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '0')]
l [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0')]
s [('1', '0', '0')]
t [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0')]
u [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0')]
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to write a reducer that takes each line as input and returns an output of:

```
a 2 1 1
b 1 0 0
e 2 0 1
f 2 0 0
i 3 0 0
l 2 0 0
t 1 0 0
u 2 0 0
```

So that it is adding together the same indexes of a tuple together and only returns one.

I have some sample code from a similar problem that I am trying to change around to work on this:

```
import sys


#The function read_mapper_output is similar to the function in group-by-key.py
def read_mapper_output(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.strip().split(' ')

#Read the input one by one
for vec in read_mapper_output(sys.stdin):
    #The first element after split is the word
    word = vec[0]
    #Count the number of ones
    count = sum(int(number) for number in vec[1:])
    #Print the word followed by number
    print("%s %d" % (word, count))
```

The error I am getting is:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[('1',"

I believe it's saying it can't work on strings, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: You need to use `ast.literal_eval(vec[1])` to parse it.

Comment: @Barmar [not so simple](https://dpaste.org/8fBcU)

Comment: The error is telling you that the input text, `a [('1', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '1')]` is not getting parsed correct by `read_mapper_output()` and `sum(int(number) for number in vec[1:])`. You'll need to parse the 1's and 0's out of that text.

Comment: @roganjosh Should be `for row in inp.splitlines()`

Comment: post your sample `file` contents

Comment: Your error message is because of your statement `yield line.strip().split(' ')` It is splitting the tuples as well as the `vec[0]`. Limit the split to just the first blank space `yield line.strip().split(' ', maxsplit=1)` And then, it will be necessary to `ast.literal_eval(vec[1])` (from Barmar)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval


with open('data.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        # skip empty line:
        if line == '':
            continue
        val, lst = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        lst = literal_eval(lst)
        print(val, *(sum(map(int, t)) for t in zip(*lst)))
```

Prints:

```
a 2 1 1
b 1 0 0
e 2 0 1
f 2 0 0
i 3 1 0
l 2 0 0
s 1 0 0
t 2 0 0
u 2 0 0
```

---

EDIT: To keep the structure of script from the question:

```py
import sys
from ast import literal_eval

#The function read_mapper_output is similar to the function in group-by-key.py
def read_mapper_output(file):
    for line in map(str.strip, file):
        if line == "":
            continue
        val, lst = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        yield val, literal_eval(lst)

#Read the input one by one
for word, lst in read_mapper_output(sys.stdin):
    #Count the number of ones
    count = (sum(map(int, t)) for t in zip(*lst))
    print(word, *count)
```

Comment: I am trying to keep the original function in the sample code since it works better on large files using yield.